# How to add millions of numbers in nodejs without blocking the further execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nonblocking

I am trying to implement the solution of a problem in node js that is:

For example:

Ur is:  http://localhost/sum/5

Should return

"The sum of numbers from 1 to 5 is: 15"

If

URL: http://localhost/sum/100

The answer should be:

"The sum of numbers from 1 to 100 is: 4950"

The parameter can be huge:

for example:

URL: http://localhost/sum/100000000
(ten million)

At no time the server should be stuck processing only one request.

I read somewhere setImmediate might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sharing a code snippet that could help someone-

```
var sum = 0
function run(number, cb) {
  sum += number;
  if(number === 15000) {
        return cb(sum);
  }
  ++number;
  setImmediate(run, number, cb);
}

run(1, (result) => {
  if(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

The above code snippet simply adds 15000 number and returns the result in response. Everything is being managed by setImmediate method. Read more from here- https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Answer (score 1):

The sum of 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n can be represented by n(n + 1) / 2. See  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) link for more info.

Comment: Hi flott, thanks for the answer thats a mathematical formula. that works but I want to do this thing using a program, using loops and all. I am looking for some function of node js or javascript that will allow me to add million of numbers without hanging the browser. like setImmediate of something.

Comment: I think that is not what he wanted to hear. Even thou the formula is correct.

Comment: If you are aiming to solve exactly the problem that you are presenting, using the mathematical formula is without doubt the most efficient approach. If that was just an example for a resource that requires much computation I see this is not the right solution. If the problem you are presenting is the one that you really want to solve, why would you want to brute force loop it instead of implementing the simple formula?

Comment: Yes, you are right! But that is the simple solution of my problem. Consider a case where I need to upload 10000 files at time. It will hang up my browser. So, I am looking for a solution that will work without hanging the user browser.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your problem exactly, if you want to make things seem like they are being processed in parallel you should use some thread library. Else I guess you need to consider the fact that you only got a finite amount of processing resources and either split it up or make use of smarter algorithms to get things done.

Comment: hmm ok, Thanks flott

Answer (score 1):

In general when you want non blocking execution, you can use the child_process module:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

An example would look something like this:

```
//fork a new process
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./intensiveTask.js',[],{});

//listen for messages from the child process
child.on('message', function(ret) {
    console.log("child process has finished", ret.data);
    //kill the child process
    child.kill();
});

//send a message to the child process
child.send({msg: "Foo"});
```

Here is the code of the child process (intensiveTask.js)

```
process.on('message', function(data) {
    //do the intensive work here
    var output=data.msg + " Bar";
    //send the output back to the parent
    process.send({msg: output});

});
```